# How do you compress included Twig JavaScript files in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig

In Symfony2 I have a number of standard JavaScript files I include and compress into one file using the Twig YUI filter like so:

```
{% javascripts
    '@WebIlluminationShopBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.js' 
    '@WebIlluminationShopBundle/Resources/public/js/ui.js' 
    '@WebIlluminationShopBundle/Resources/public/js/tools.js' 
    '@WebIlluminationShopBundle/Resources/public/js/overlay.js' 
    '@WebIlluminationShopBundle/Resources/public/js/uniform.js' 
    '@WebIlluminationShopBundle/Resources/public/js/slider.js' 
    '@WebIlluminationShopBundle/Resources/public/js/global.js' 
    output='js/shop-compressed.js' filter='yui_js' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Within my Twig templates I then include specific JavaScript Twig files, which have data passed to them as variables from the controller:

```
{% include 'SomeCompanySomeBundle:ControllerName:testScript.js.twig' with {'variable1': variable1, 'variable2': variable2} %}
```

Is there a way to compress this JavaScript like I would the main JavaScript files I use using the YUI filter?

It may not be possible, but just wondered if someone new for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig generated JS files needs to be refreshed with Twig context on each request, son it's not possible !

Comment: I don't see why it's not possible. All the surrounding JS could be pre-compressed and cached, and then the [uncompressed] context can be subbed in at run-time. Alternatively, you could do the compression at run-time after subbing in the context (potentially resulting in even smaller files), but this would be slow(er).